# Delete Z Coordinates in json file usin python

Tags: python

Given a GeoJSON like following:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
                                                                                
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID_2": 4992, "OBJECTID": 0, "AREA": 0.000000, "Shape_Leng": 0.000000, "Shape_Area": 936.751154, "partialBuilding": 1.000000, "partialDec": 0.053525 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 121.591767286970708, 31.257540900075529, 0.0 ], [ 121.59176711413663, 31.25756247077992, 0.0 ], [ 121.591784548639708, 31.257562572913027, 0.0 ], [ 121.591924199999241, 31.257563390411246, 0.0 ], [ 121.591924199999241, 31.257540900075529, 0.0 ], [ 121.591767286970708, 31.257540900075529, 0.0 ] ] ] } }
```

How can I delete the Z coordinates "0,0" and save the data on the same JSON file?

So far I have this:

```
import json
with open('data.geojson') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for feature in data['features']:

    feature['geometry']['coordinates'] =  feature['geometry']['coordinates'] .replace(', 0.0','0')

with open('data.geojson', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

I get this problem
attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: your question title says deleting z coordinate in your code you are trying to replace it. what exactly are you trying to do? `list` doesn't have `replace` method

Comment: if i replace " , 0.0" with "0" it will be the same as deleting " ,0.0" as the added 0 will be added to the Y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
feature["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]=[x[:-1] for x in feature["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the accepted answer will not apply the same fix to the hole part of a geojson coordinates. I would improve it with this (not a one-liner but a bit more readable):

```
coordinates = feature["geometry"]["coordinates"]
cleaned_coordinates = []
for linear_ring in coordinates:
    cleaned_linear_ring = [point[:2] for point in linear_ring]
    cleaned_coordinates.append(cleaned_linear_ring)
```